# How do I enable GNOME system tools?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, administration

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 with GNOME 2.30.2.  This is a VMWare workstation image provided by another company that I do not have support in this regard.  I am trying to access the graphical tools for configuring the network, users, and services but the System->Administration menu does not have these options listed.

The main issue I am trying to solve is to correct the problems with the GNOME menu options and network settings.

I have the `gnome-system-tools` package installed, and I am unable to run command-line versions of the tools, such as `nm-applet` (I get no GUI if I run that command, the process is running in the background).

I realize that I can perform many tasks command-line, but I would like to use the GUI for administrative functions as I am not overly proficient for all command for restarting services and setting a static IP with a specific gateway.

Further, I can run `gnome-nettool`, but I cannot change the IP, I can only see my network card.  `nm-connection-editor` does not show any network cards that I can configure to change the IP.

Currently, I am getting a DHCP through my NAT in VMWare, I want to set it to a specific IP address though.

Preferences Menu (note some missing options)

[image: Preferences Menu]

Administration Menu (note some missing options)

[image: Admin Menu]

Network Tools  (I can view but not change IP address)

[image: Network Tools]

Network Settings (Unable to change IP address)

[image: Network Settings]

Network Connections (no connections listed, not even my existing ethernet NAT connection through VMWare)

[image: Network Connections]

Answer (score 2):

I hope I got you right on what you are trying to do.

`Network Connections` is in `Preferences` but you can also start is from the terminal using `nm-connection_editor`.

`Users and Groups` is in `Administration` you can start this one from the terminal too using `users-admin`.

To manage applications which should start automatically on a system start you use the `Startup Applications Preferences` application which is in `Preferences` again.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the command line applications (note the screenshots above), but I am unable to get to a view (GUI) where I can change the IP address.  I believe I should see a wired entry in Network Connections to Edit, but as I illustrated, there is no entry

Answer (score 1):

You can try some things.

- `sudo /etc/init.d/networing restart` to restart your network.
- `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart` to restart your network-manager tool.
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nm-applet gnome-nettool` to remanufacture your network packages.
- `sudo gnome-nettool` to try open `gnome-nettool` in root mode, but it didn't work for me. If didn't try it yet, try to move to tty1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), log in as your user, and type `sudo xinit gnome-applet -- :1` to open a windows with `gnome-applet` tool setted as root.

If you can use or are using KDE, I recommend KNetworkManager (`sudo apt-get install knetworkmanager`); I use it and I like it very much.

Answer (score 1):

If my memory serves me for 10.04 the nm-applet provides the network icon in the right hand side of the top panel. You can initiate configuration functions and view connection information by clicking the network manager icon and the selecting the desired function which are performed in GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Network Connections etc should be in Preferences not Administration. Users and Groups is not in Administration?